# Is there more than one invisibility cloak in the HP world?

Tags: harry-potter

I've finished reading the 4th book, *Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire*, and I've noticed that in Moody's trunk there is a second invisibility cloak. Or was it the second one? Is there more than one invisibility cloak in the world? If so then is it not a deathly hallow?

What am I missing? At first I was thinking that the cloak in Moody's trunk was the one belonging to Harry but it seems he had his cloak with him or did Moody not return it sometime after the after-bath scene?

Comment: Later (during Deathly Hallows) Ron remarks to Harry that his invisibility cloak is significantly better than any other one he has seen. Usually the cloaks magic fades over time, and the cloak is ruined, but Harry's cloak has stood the test of time without any diminishing quality and enables perfect invisibility.

Comment: You mention deathly hallows. Does that mean you already read book 7? Because the answer to your question is a spoiler if you didn't.

Comment: @Fabian I know the other books and films, I watched and read them before, some 5-7 years ago. I'm rereading the books in English now.

Comment: There are multiple invisibility cloaks. There are also multiple wands and multiple stones.

Comment: Have you read all the Harry Potter books? It should explain the deathly hallows cloak a bit more in The Deathly Hallows.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

There are multiple invisibility cloaks in the world, but they are not all like the Cloak of Invisibility. The difference is outlined by Xenophilius Lovegood in this quote.

> ‘Ah, but the Third Hallow is a true cloak of invisibility, Miss Granger! I mean to say, it is not a travelling cloak imbued with a Disillusionment Charm, or carrying a Bedazzling Hex, or else woven from Demiguise hair, which will hide one initially but fade with the years until it turns opaque. We are talking about a cloak that really and truly renders the wearer completely invisible, and endures eternally, giving constant and impenetrable concealment, no matter what spells are cast at it. How many cloaks have you ever seen like that, Miss Granger?’
>   <sub>Deathly Hallows - Chapter 21: The Tale of the Three Brothers</sub>

So the cloaks that Moody owns, or that Barty Crouch Jr or Mr. Weasley used (in *Goblet of Fire* and *The Order of the Phoenix* respectively), are just regular cloaks with various charms placed on them. They are not Deathly Hallows and will eventually cease to work.

The Cloak of Invisibility that Harry owns is a true invisibility cloak, supposedly made by Death, that has been in use for generations and has never failed and (presumably) never will.

Comment: "supposedly made by Death" - I thought it was canon that the Hallows were created by Peverell brothers themselves?

Comment: I think you are right, but in-universe the story is that Death made the Hallows.

Comment: I believe that death cut it off from his own cloak, so I suppose there are two invisibility cloaks - Harry’s and Death’s.

Comment: @Tim didn’t he give his own cloak away completely?

Comment: @11684 I’ve not read the books recently but in the film death is seen using a claw to slice his cloak. I do not know if that is canon.

Comment: Another point: some death eater tries "accio cloak" once, but the True Cloak is unaffected by it. Presumably, the "imitation" cloaks may not have the same anti-summoning protection, although I believe anti-summoning charms do exist in-universe.

Comment: "has never failed and (presumably) never will." Well, Moody's eye seems to be able to see through it.

Answer (score 22):

Yes, there is more than one invisibility cloak. In Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them (the first one, the book), it is mentioned that they are made out of demiguise hair. However, non-hallow cloaks are either not made by Death (or not made by a super powerful wizard depending on your interpretation) and notably:

- go "off" after a decade or so not granting true invisibility just a sort of glassy effect slowly becoming more opaque over time.
- do not provide invisibility against Death himself (again depending on interpretation of the deathly hallows story.)

Invisibility cloaks are also supposedly very expensive as the demiguise can itself become invisible making it hard to catch, hence why they are rarely seen (well that and the whole invisible when on a person thing).

It's a bit like the difference between regular wands and the elder wand.

Answer (score 19):

It was very clear from the last book that the Cloak which Harry possessed was the original Invisibility Cloak and the Hallows do exist.

> “The Hallows, the Hallows,” murmured Dumbledore. “A desperate man’s
> dream!”
>
> “But they’re real!”
>
> “**Real, and dangerous, and a lure for fools**,” said Dumbledore.
>
> “So it’s true?” asked Harry. “All of it? The Peverell brothers—”
>
> “—were the three brothers of the tale,” said Dumbledore, nodding.

.

> You have guessed, I know, why the Cloak was in my possession on the
> night your parents died. James had showed it to me just a few days
> previously. It explained so much of his undetected wrong-doing at
> school! I could hardly believe what I was seeing. I asked to borrow
> it, to examine it. I had long since given up my dream of uniting the
> Hallows, but I could not resist, could not help taking a closer look .
> . . **It was a Cloak the likes of which I had never seen, immensely
> old, perfect in every respect.**
>
> *Deathly Hallows, Ch 35: King's Cross*

Also, Xenophilius made it very clear when the Trio goes to meet him that there are Invisibility Cloaks available in the market but there is only one "true" Hallow.

> “Ah, but the Third Hallows is true Cloak of Invisibility, Miss
> Granger! **I mean to say, it is not a traveling cloak imbued with a
> Disillusionment Charm, or carrying a Bedazzling Hex or else woven from
> Demiguise hair, which will hide one initially but fade with the years
> until it turns opaque.** We are talking about a cloak that really and
> truly renders the wearer completely invisible, and endures eternally,
> giving constant and impenetrable concealment, no matter what spells
> are cast at it. How many cloaks have you ever seen like that, Miss
> Granger?”
>
> *Deathly Hallows, Ch 21, The Tale of Three Brothers*

So i guess the Cloak which Moody possessed was one which was charmed or made from a special material. The fact that such Cloaks existed was not really news.