# Uniqueness of invisibility cloaks

Tags: harry-potter, invisibility-cloak

I am currently reading *Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince* and a question occurred to me. According to the story of the Deathly Hallows, the invisibility cloak is the third one. But in the previous books, we saw that many wizards own an invisibility cloak (like Mundungus, for example). How is that possible? As it is one of the three Deathly Hallows, shouldn't it be unique?

As I said, I've not finished the books, only the movies. Therefore, this question may be answered in the next book but still.. I would like to know the answer as there isn't any explanation in the movies.

Comment: There are other invisibility cloaks but they're not as powerful or as long lasting (IIRC) as the true Clock of Invisibility that Harry has. I'm sure I've seen a question about this on the site before.

Comment: I don't want to hammer it myself but [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/180456/58193) seems like it would be a duplicate of what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there more than one invisibility cloak in the HP world?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/180456/is-there-more-than-one-invisibility-cloak-in-the-hp-world)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot *the true Clock of Invisibility* - great typo... if it hadn't made me chuckle midway through a mouthful of tea I'd probably find it even more amusing :p

Comment: @JonClements I won't mod abuse to fix it then :)